# Can serverless express be used with sails.js apps

Tags: express, sails.js, aws-lambda

Strange that google does not have any info for this...

I want to use aws lambda for an upcoming project. I would like to build it with sails.js. I know that there is aws-serverless-express that allows to run express apps on lambda. Does this also apply to sails or would this not work?

Comment: have you got any suitable solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `waterline.js` successfully with express and serverless on AWS Lambda. [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) is the ORM component of Sails.js.

Under the hood of Sails it uses express so it would be possible to with serverless. Although as Manuel mentions it may be too fat for Lambda.

```
const PGAdapter = require('sails-postgresql');
const Waterline = require('waterline');

const conf = {
  "adapters":{
    "sails-postgresql": PGAdapter
  },
  "datastores":{
    "default":{
      "adapter":"sails-postgresql",
      "port":5432,
      "poolSize":1,
      "ssl":false,
      "database":"development",
      "host":"localhost",
      "user":"***",
      "password":"****"
    }
  },
  "models":{
    "User":{
      "tableName":"users",
      "attributes":{
        "email":{
          "type":"string",
          "required":true
        },
        "first_name":{
          "type":"string"
        },
        "last_name":{
          "type":"string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultModelSettings":{
    "primaryKey":"id",
    "datastore":"default",
    "attributes":{
      "id":{
        "type":"number",
        "autoMigrations":{
          "autoIncrement":true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And before my express routes I create a middleware function that hooks on my models to the app.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  let waterline = conf;
  Waterline.start(waterline, function(err, orm) {
    if(err) {
      console.error('Could not start up the ORM:\n',err);
      return process.exit(1);
    }
    app.models = {
      User: Waterline.getModel('user', orm)
    }
    next();
  });
});
```

The result in use.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  app.models.User.findOne({ id: 2 }).exec(function (err, result){
    console.log('err:', err);
    console.log('result:', result);
    res.json(result);
  });
});
```

With some tweaking you can house your models in external files and autoload them in. And swap out database details based on environment. Here is the configuration function I use.

```
const PGAdapter = require('sails-postgresql');

function createWaterlineConf(db, models) {
  const defaults = {
    adapter:    'sails-postgresql',
    port: 5432,
    poolSize: 10,
    ssl: true
  };
  const databaseConf = Object.assign(defaults, db);

  const waterlineConf = {

    adapters: {
      'sails-postgresql': PGAdapter
    },

    datastores: {
      default: databaseConf
    },

    models: models,

    defaultModelSettings: {
      primaryKey: 'id',
      datastore: 'default',
      attributes: {
        id: { type: 'number', autoMigrations: { autoIncrement: true } },
      }
    }

  };
  return waterlineConf;
}

module.exports.createWaterlineConf = createWaterlineConf;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using sails.js, but I wouldn't put it into a Lambda function as it is too fat, needs seconds to boot and that works against the usage profile of a Lambda function. Of course, I understand that it would be nice to have your already implemented models and services in a Lambda function - I will also run into this.

If you still want to try it, you can

- strip down the Lambda sails.js (disable as much as possible in `.sailsrc` and disable as many middlewares as possible) and
- try to use Lambda's same-container strategy ([Example how MongoDB does it](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/optimizing-aws-lambda-performance-with-mongodb-atlas-and-nodejs))